# Как автоматически определить новые файлы в каталоге с последующей их обработкой?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, service

Eсть каталог с именем "Файлы". Программа при запуске считывает все данные из всех фалов, файлы удаляет. Позже, при добавлении в этот каталог файла, например, скопировали его туда, программа должна сама сразу его прочитать и удалить.

Kак будет более эффективно сделать процесс/службу, которые следят за папкой "Файлы", или ограничиться только обычным приложением?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть компонент в среде **FileSystemWatcher**, который позволяет отслеживать то, что вы хотите.
Примеры работы с ним есть в интернете

[Описание](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

[Урок по работе с компонентом](http://www.programmers.kz/programming/ssh/uroki_c_sharp/14642-urok-59-klass-filesystemwatcher.html)